# Jquery Tools Tabs: How to capture onClick event when selection is on current tab?

Tags: jquery-tools

I tried to ask this question on the jquery tools forum, but didn't get a response, hopefully someone here can help.

Question: 
It seems the onClick event does not get fired when user is already on current tab, I think that make sense for most cases. However, in my case, I do want to capture the onClick event even when the curent tab is already the selection.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can always bind the onClick event to the anchor tags themselves rather than to the tabs events.